# How to change default conjunction with Lucene MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: lucene, operators

I have some code using Lucene that leaves the default conjunction operator as OR, and I want to change it to AND.  Some of the code just uses a plain QueryParser, and that's fine - I can just call setDefaultOperator on those instances.

Unfortunately, in one place the code uses a MultiFieldQueryParser, and calls the static "parse" method (taking String, String[], BooleanClause.Occur[], Analyzer), so it seems that setDefaultOperator can't help, because it's an instance method.

Is there a way to keep using the same parser but have the default conjunction changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `MultiFieldQueryParser` class extends the `QueryParser` class. Perhaps you could simply configure an instance of this class rather than relying on its static methods? If you really need to configure the `BooleanClause.Occur` values, you could do it afterward.

```
String queryString = ...;
String[] fields = ...;
Analyzer analyzer = ...;

MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);

Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString);

// If you're not happy with MultiFieldQueryParser's default Occur (SHOULD), you can re-configure it afterward:
if (query instanceof BooleanQuery) {
    BooleanClause.Occur[] flags = ...;
    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = (BooleanQuery) query;
    BooleanClause[] clauses = booleanQuery.getClauses();
    for (int i = 0; i < clauses.length; i++) {
        clauses[i].setOccur(flags[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good thanks.  The missing step was how to configure the Occur values afterwards.

Another approach I'm toying with is that the code for MultiFieldQueryParser.parse is tiny, so I might just paste that into my application and modify it.  It creates QueryParser instances itself, so I can just tweak it to set the default operator on them.

Comment: Within the iterated for loop, you can also use the following to change the conjunction per field:

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.YOUR_VERSION, fields[i], new YourAnalyzer());
                    parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
                    clause.setQuery(parser.parse(clause.getQuery().toString(fields[i])));